# DRR: createType(ExtrinsicStatus):: Cannot map Enum JSON, unable to find 'reason' in future, ready, broadcast, inblock, retracted, finalitytimeout

Tags: polkadot, api, extrinsicstatus

When I run the following code in some calls I get the following errors:

- DRR: createType(ExtrinsicStatus):: Cannot map Enum JSON, unable to find 'reason' in future, ready, broadcast, inblock, retracted, finalitytimeout, finalized, usurped, dropped, invalid
- CORE: submitAndWatchExtrinsic(extrinsic: Extrinsic): ExtrinsicStatus:: -32601: Method not found

are these errors occur because of some runtime differences?
(endpoint: "wss://kusama-rpc.polkadot.io")

```
import { ApiPromise } from '@polkadot/api'; // "^7.11.1"
import { SubmittableExtrinsic } from '@polkadot/api/types';
import { KeyringPair } from '@polkadot/keyring/types'; //"^8.4.1"
import { ISubmittableResult } from '@polkadot/types/types'; //"^7.11.2-1"

export async function signAndSend (api: ApiPromise, submittable: SubmittableExtrinsic<'promise', ISubmittableResult>, _signer: KeyringPair, senderAddress: string): Promise<TxInfo> {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {

void submittable.signAndSend(_signer, async (result) => {
  let txFailed = false;
  let failureText: string;

  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)));

  if (result.dispatchError) {
    if (result.dispatchError.isModule) {
      // for module errors, we have the section indexed, lookup
      const decoded = api.registry.findMetaError(result.dispatchError.asModule);
      const { docs, name, section } = decoded;

      txFailed = true;
      failureText = `${docs.join(' ')}`;

      console.log(`dispatchError module: ${section}.${name}: ${docs.join(' ')}`);
    } else {
      // Other, CannotLookup, BadOrigin, no extra info
      console.log(`dispatchError other reason: ${result.dispatchError.toString()}`);
    }
  }

  if (result.status.isFinalized) { 
    const hash = result.status.isFinalized ? result.status.asFinalized : result.status.asInBlock;
    const signedBlock = await api.rpc.chain.getBlock(hash);
    const blockNumber = signedBlock.block.header.number;
    const txHash = result.txHash.toString();

    // search for the hash of the extrinsic in the block
    signedBlock.block.extrinsics.forEach(async (ex) => {
      if (ex.isSigned) {
        if (String(ex.signer) == senderAddress) {
          const queryInfo = await api.rpc.payment.queryInfo(ex.toHex(), signedBlock.block.hash);
          const fee = queryInfo.partialFee.toString();

          resolve({ block: Number(blockNumber), failureText: failureText, fee: fee, status: txFailed ? 'failed' : 'success', txHash: txHash });
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

});
}

Comment: please include the versions of software you are using and the nodes you are connected to (and their versions)

Comment: `submitAndWatchExtrinsic` + `Method not found` is certainly weird.

Comment: I see the same sporadically on `kusama-rpc.polkadot.io` - it is like some nodes in the RPC cluster is running a very weird version. Some work, some does not and have this issue. Seems like a broken deployment in the cluster, imho.

Answer (score 2):

This was caused by the testing (pre-release) versions of the RPC nodes running the new [jsonrpsee server](https://github.com/paritytech/jsonrpsee). The best way to test RPC nodes is under load...

It has been addressed since this was raised, i.e. the [Polkadot 0.9.22 version](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases/tag/v0.9.22) that went out did contain a version of jsonrpsee a fix for this issue. (Here I could point directly to a release containing it, however the actual fix went in very quickly when this was uncovered and was subsequently deployed on the nodes running the burn-in testing versions)

TL;DR It should not occur anymore.